# question about 午前n時

Tags: kanji

I'm learning Japanese and I just finished learning Hiragana and Katakana and now I'm moving to Kanji. In my studies I found that 午前8時 means 8 a.m Ok, that's cool but I would like to know how to pronunciate it.

Should I just combine the sounds? I mean 午 is ご, 前 is まえ and 時とき so 午前8時 would be ごまえ8とき?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kanji have kun and on-yomi. In this case, the correct pronunciation would be ごぜん　はち　じ

Comment: Thank you! These rules are kinda confusing for me yet. In this case we have 4 words right? ご+ぜん+はち+じ

Comment: No, ごぜん　is a whole word which represents the period of time between midnight and mid-day

Comment: Oh! Thank you again. The website I'm using to learn Kanj should say that, would be helpful. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Indeed, はちじ is also one word, albeit a predictible and divisible one. It's fairly unusual to find words made of a single kanji's on-yomi.